# Why is this bang in the If Then Failing Here

Tags: javascript

The value in div *PermanentHiddenDiv3* can be -11, 1, 6, 12, 17, 18 or 29.

However, at the point in the script where this code exists, the value should
only ever be 18.  So, I could go with that.

On the other hand, if I could get this to work with other values being
handled as well, it would be better.

```
var OMGxAlgebra = function(evt){
    var AltReality = document.getElementById("Latent29");
    var AreYouSAVED;
    var SingleEval = document.getElementById("PermanentHiddenDiv3");
    var ThinkingIsAntiSocial = SingleEval.textContent;
    OhItIS = ThinkingIsAntiSocial*1;

     //  You can write this ::
     //          if(OhItIS==18){
     //              AreYouSAVED="";
     //              AltReality.textContent=AreYouSAVED;
     //          }        
    if(OhItIS==18){
    AreYouSAVED="";
    AltReality.textContent=AreYouSAVED;
    }        
};
```

The code above works, but the next does not.  I thought that in JavaScript
this syntax was valid  ???

```
if(!somevar==X){}

if(!OhItIS==29){
    AreYouSAVED="";
    AltReality.textContent=AreYouSAVED;
}
```

The code in context : http://jsfiddle.net/MountainMan72/4gySs/    ... just in case
I am missing some external tripwire.

Comment: Those are some of the most horrible names I've ever seen...

Comment: Hmmm.  Noted.  By the way, some time ago I stumbled on your blog post *What Have You Tried*  Great material.  Thanks for the quarter million plus measure of help to the community :)

Comment: That's not my blog post. But it is a belief I hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want to use `OhItIS != 29`

Using `!OhItIS == 29` converts OhItIs to a boolean value and compares that to 29. Obviously ends in results that you don't want.

Try this in your browser for verification:

```
var ohitis = 29;
console.log(!ohitis);
```

This should print out `false`;

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
if (OhItIS != 29){
    AreYouSAVED="";
    AltReality.textContent=AreYouSAVED;
}
```

The bang goes before the =

```
!=
```

Comment: OhItIs!=29 - "OhItIs is not equal to 29".... !OhItIs==29 - "Not OhItIs is equal to 29"

Answer (score 2):

The precedence rules mean that `!x==y` parses as `(!x) == y`, not `!(x == y)`. As the other answers said, use `x != y` to avoid the problem.